# Pinning R package versions

Tags: r

How do you best pin package versions in R?

**Rejected strategy 1:** Pin to CRAN source `tar.gz`s

- Doesn't work if you want to pin it at the latest version since CRAN does not put the tip version in the archive (duh)

**Rejected strategy 2:** Use `devtools`

- Don't want to, because it takes ages to compile and adds lots of stuff I don't want to use

**Rejected strategy 3:** Vendor

- Would rather avoid having to copy all source

Comment: What you mean by 'pin' isn't clear, but I think you want packrat https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/ which controls package versioning for a project.

Comment: pin as in set to a particular version to be used when building. `packrat` is basically a vendoring lib as I understand it?

Comment: I believe so, I've never actually used it but am aware of it. For that reason I put it as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: There are similar questions already on SO, such as this one which suggests virtual machines as a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860802/how-to-install-and-manage-many-versions-of-r-packages?rq=1

Comment: well, the destination for my package builds are a docker container :-). I need a way to set it to particular versions to be used in production and for reproducibility.

Comment: I once tried the [miniCRAN](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/miniCRAN) way and it was quite convenient. It adds some maintenance work though.You can either host a network sub-repository with a "frozen" snapshot (as I did) or distribute the package bundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To provide a little bit more information on `packrat`, which I use for this purpose.  From the [website](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/).

> R package dependencies can be frustrating. Have you ever had to use
>   trial-and-error to figure out what R packages you need to install to
>   make someone else’s code work–and then been left with those packages
>   globally installed forever, because now you’re not sure whether you
>   need them? Have you ever updated a package to get code in one of your
>   projects to work, only to find that the updated package makes code in
>   another project stop working?
>
> We built packrat to solve these problems. Use packrat to make your R
>   projects more:
>
> Isolated: Installing a new or updated package for one project won’t
>   break your other projects, and vice versa. That’s because packrat
>   gives each project its own private package library. Portable: Easily
>   transport your projects from one computer to another, even across
>   different platforms. Packrat makes it easy to install the packages
>   your project depends on. Reproducible: Packrat records the exact
>   package versions you depend on, and ensures those exact versions are
>   the ones that get installed wherever you go.

Packrat stores the version of the packages you use in the `packrat.lock` file, and then downloads that version from CRAN whenever you `packrat::restore()`.  It is much lighter weight than `devtools`, but can still take some time to re-download all of the packages (depending on the packages you are using).

If you prefer to store all of the sources in a `zip` file, you can use `packrat::snapshot()` to pull down the sources / update the `packrat.lock` and then `packrat::bundle()` to "bundle" everything up.  The aim for this is to make projects / research reproducible and portable over time by storing the package versions and dependencies used on the original design (along with the source code so that the OS dependency on a binary is avoided).

There is much more information on the website I linked to, and you can see current activity on the [git repo](https://github.com/rstudio/packrat).  I have encountered a few cases that work in a less-than-ideal way (packages not on CRAN have some issues at times), but the git repo still seems to be pretty active with issues/patches which is encouraging.