# Pin R packages and notifications of new versions of packages

Tags: r, package

Is there any way to pin specific R packages so they stop of being update? I know about [Packrat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45372260/6888648), but I'm looking for something more system or user wide.

On the other hand I would like to receive a notification –an email– when a new version of specific packages reach CRAN. I've been looking for something like that, but I can find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to R then go to the section tools > Check for package updates

Comment: I'm looking for something outside the RStudio interface. I like to update R packages in command line, terminal, and I just run `Rscript --vanilla -e "update.packages(ask = F, repos = 'cloud.r-project.org')"`. I would like to be notified when `data.table` is updated.

Comment: i hope this link helps u : https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/get-notified-when-r-packages-update

Comment: I knew about that, but I can't see that option in the rdocumentation.com page https://www.rdocumentation.org/. Is it deprecated?

Comment: true, there's no option, then i found the cran mail list for packages where u can subscribe: https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-packages

Comment: I know that list and I’m subscribed, but not all the packages are announced there. I would say that usually aren’t announced there.